# Django forms: cannot access local variable 'form' where it is not associated with a value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

**Condition:** I have a model, created an empty table in the database, and I'm trying to create an html form that will fill in the fields of the corresponding columns of the table.
And here's what my app looks like:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Cities(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.state   

class Routes(models.Model):
    route_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Route')
    lvl = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    total_distance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    city = models.ForeignKey(Cities, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Routes

class RouteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Routes
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponse

from routes_form.forms import RouteForm


def getAbout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RouteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'routes_form/form_page.html', {'form': form})
```

**form.html**

```
<form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <legend>
            <h2>About</h2>
        </legend>
        {{ form }}
        <input type="text" placeholder="Write more about the route: about waypoints, points of interest and warnings.">
        <input type="submit" value="Send route">
</form>
```

I have already tried to do everything as indicated in the Django Forms documentation. But still something is wrong. Even at the moment of starting the server, it writes an error:

```
cannot access local variable 'form' where it is not associated with a value
```

Comment: You have to pass the parameter 'context' in order to gain acccess to the variable 'form'. Try `return render(request, 'routes_form/form_page.html', context={'form': form})`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work, but thanks to your answer, I found the problem. And now I will solve it. The point was that the form variable was local and was not visible when it was returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you passed `form = RouteForm(request.POST)` object for `POST` request you need to pass for `GET` request so, when def `getAbout(request)` function called with GET request then renders it like this ...

```
def getAbout(request):
  form=RouteForm() # <---- called at GET request
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RouteForm(request.POST) # <---- called at POST request
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save()
      return redirect("/")
  return render(request, 'routes_form/form_page.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you haven't defined `form` for `GET` method so:

```py
def getAbout(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RouteForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('some_view_name_to_redirect')
    else:
        form=RouteForm()
    return render(request, 'routes_form/form_page.html', {'form': form})
```

> **Note:** Models in Django are written in singular form, as Django itself add `s` as the suffix, so it is better to name the models as `City` and `Route`.